# Google Analytics Events present in console but no more in Api v4 results

Tags: python, api, google-analytics

I wanted to install Google Analytics Events to retrieve and calculate clicks on each of a serie of 10 images:

I use the following code:

```
<div onclick="ga('send','event','timelineb','pic10','1025902x10');">.......
```

I use the code provided by Google: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py

I just changed the report to:

```
  return analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': [
        {
          'viewId': VIEW_ID,
          'pageSize': 10000,
          'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '7daysAgo', 'endDate':  "today"}],
          'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:eventValue'}],
          'dimensions': [
                {'name': 'ga:eventLabel'},
                #{'name': 'ga:eventAction'},
                {'name': 'ga:eventCategory'}
                ],
        }]
      }
  ).execute()
```

On output I get old values (at the time I had put timeline instead of timelineb)

```
Date range: 0
ga:eventValue: 9
ga:eventLabel: 2148641
ga:eventCategory: timeline
```

I only see the old eventCategory "timeline" but not the new eventCategory "timelineb".

I waited a little and clicked several times to generate events but nothing appears.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling a bit I have discovered that I need to use the ga:uniqueEvents in the metrics configuration. Now every events are displaying fine.

```
  return analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': [
        {
          'viewId': VIEW_ID,
          'pageSize': 10000,
          'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '7daysAgo', 'endDate':  "today"}],
          'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:uniqueEvents'}],
          'dimensions': [
                {'name': 'ga:eventLabel'}, 
                {'name': 'ga:eventCategory'}
                ],
        }]
      }
  ).execute()
```

And change

```
<div onclick="ga('send','event','timelineb','pic10','1025902x10');">.......
```

to

```
<div onclick="ga('send','event','timelineb','pic10','1025902x10', 1);">.......
```

It is important to Add 1 to event value, seems to be used to be multiplied by the number of clicks.

Hope this help.